# php codeigniter don't update variable to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a problem with my PHP project with CodeIgniter.

I have a form in which I pass variables to the Database and execute an UPDATE Query by modifying the data on the Database.

The problem is that when I insert the new data it does not give me error, it shows me the view in which it shows the data of the table but the data are not modified.

Can anyone help me understand please?

**MODELS** ***Hello_Model.php***

```
function displayrecordsById($id)
 {
 $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM Todolist WHERE id='".$id."'");
 return $query->result();
 }

 function updaterecords($testo,$stato,$id)
 {
     $this->db->query("update Todolist SET testo='$testo',stato='$stato' WHERE id='".$id."'");

 }
```

**Views** ***update_records.php***

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Registration form</title>
</head>

<body>
 <?php
  //$i=1;
  foreach($data as $row)
  {
  ?>
    <form method="post">
        <table width="600" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td width="230">Id </td>
    <td width="329"><input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Testo </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="testo" value="<?php echo $row->testo; ?>"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Stato</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='stato' value= "<?php echo $row->stato; ?> "/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
    <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Records"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
    </form>
    <?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
</html>
```

**Controllers** ***Hello.php***

```
public function updatedata()
 {
 $id=$this->input->get('id');
 $result['data']=$this->Hello_Model->displayrecordsById($id);
 $this->load->view('update_records',$result); 

 if($this->input->post('update'))
 {
 $n=$this->input->post('testo');
 $e=$this->input->post('stato');
 $this->Hello_Model->updaterecords($id,$n,$e);
 redirect("http://simone.fabriziolerose.it/index.php/Hello/dispdata");
        echo "Success!";

 }
 }
```

I took the code from [this](https://www.phptpoint.com/codeigniter-update-database-record/) tutorial

Comment: your param seq is wrong in the controller, please check

Comment: In your code, in controller function call updaterecords($id,$n,$e) change argument order based on function definition in model . change argument order to updaterecords($n,$e,$id).

action is missing in your form

Comment: Thank you all for your help, you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think problem in calling model function check:

change this:

```
$this->Hello_Model->updaterecords($id,$n,$e);
```

To

```
 $this->Hello_Model->updaterecords($n,$e,$id);
```

and you change your custom query to CI query like:

For Update

```
$this->db->where("id",$id);
$this->db->update("Todolist",array("testo"=>$testo,"stato"=>$stato));
```

For Select:

```
$this->db->where("id",$id);
$query=$this->db->get("Todolist");
$row=$query->row();
```